# Android Coroutines and WeakReferences

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, weak-references

To avoid activity leaks when using threads, handlers, etc, I always wrap the Activity, View, Context, etc., in a WeakReference, so:

```
val textViewRef = WeakReference(textView)

thread { 
    .....
    val view = textViewRef.get() ?: return@thread
    .....
}
```

For coroutines, do we need to do also the same? I mean to always wrap with WeakReferences to avoid leaks?

Comment: For coroutines, use lifecycle scoped coroutines. `lifecycleScope.launch {}` in `Activity`, `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {}` in `Fragment`, etc to process your work. Dispatch ui tasks via `Dispatchers.Main`.

Comment: I think what you do here is only a mitigation of effects of the problem, not fixing the problem itself. Root cause of your problem is that you leak background tasks and with them you leak other objects. Coroutines introduced structured concurrency, which means if you use them properly, then you don't leak background tasks and as a result, you can't leak views, etc.